# Thumbnail doesn't appear on Facebook and Google+

Tags: facebook, wordpress, google-plus

No page on my website, for example: http://insin.tk/komunikace-v-pocitacovych-sitich/
doesn't show thumbnail on Facebook or Google+ pages. When I insert link to Facebook or Google+ text area to share new post, preview shows without thumbnail.

My website is built on WP and I tried many plugins to fix this problem but nothing seems to help. For pages that I'm testing I have setup the featured image and I have also images in the page. I hope that all required meta tags I have set correctly.

I really don't know where is problem. I will be pleased for every suggestion.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Finsin.tk%2Fkomunikace-v-pocitacovych-sitich%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image URL that Google picks out returns a 500 error.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http%3A%2F%2Finsin.tk%2Fkomunikace-v-pocitacovych-sitich%2F

http://insin.tk/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/komunikace.png

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Structured Data Testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=http://insin.tk/komunikace-v-pocitacovych-sitich/) to help determine what the Google crawler can see.

Use [the Facebook object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://insin.tk/komunikace-v-pocitacovych-sitich/) to help with the Facebook side of things.

Try setting the "featured image" on your WP site. Also, there is a good plugin for OG called Stumbleupon and Digg Thumbnail maker that may be of help.